# Excel VBA Userform Dynamic Runtime Controls - Trigger Same Class Event Across Multiple Controls

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, user-controls, runtime

I am in the process of building an Excel based Application that builds itself dynamically at run-time based on external data.

Here is the empty userform:

[image]

Code within `UserForm_Activate()`

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
Dim f As Control, i As Integer

mdMenuItems.BuildMenuItems
mdTheme.GetTheme

For Each f In Me.Controls
    If TypeName(f) = "Frame" Then
        i = i + 1
        ReDim Preserve fra(1 To i)
        Set fra(i).fraEvent1 = f
    End If
Next f

End Sub
```

`mdMenuItems.BuildMenuItems` dynamically builds a series of menu items based on external data...

Code within `mdMenuItems` module

```
Option Explicit
Dim lbl() As New cMenuItem
Public myFileData As String
Public myFileValue As String
Public frmTheme As String

Sub BuildMenuItems()
Dim FileNum As Integer, i As Integer
Dim WrdArray() As String
Dim lblMenuIcon As MSForms.Label, lblMenuText As MSForms.Label, lblMenuBackground As MSForms.Label

FileNum = FreeFile()

Open Application.ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Data\MenuItems.csv" For Input As #FileNum

Do While Not EOF(FileNum)
    i = i + 1
    Line Input #FileNum, myFileData ' read in data 1 line at a time
    WrdArray() = Split(myFileData, ",")
    Set lblMenuBackground =  frmTest.frmMenuBackground.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "lblMenuBackground_" & i)
    Set lblMenuIcon = frmTest.frmMenuBackground.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "lblMenuIcon_" & i)
    Set lblMenuText = frmTest.frmMenuBackground.Controls.Add("Forms.Label.1", "lblMenuText_" & i)

    With lblMenuBackground
        .top = 30 * i
        .left = 0
        .Width = 170
        .Height = 30
        .BackColor = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        .BackStyle = fmBackStyleOpaque
        .MousePointer = fmMousePointerCustom
        .MouseIcon = LoadPicture(Application.ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Creative\Other\Hand.cur")
        .Tag = "_006"
    End With

    ReDim Preserve lbl(1 To i)
    Set lbl(i).lblEvent1 = lblMenuBackground

    With lblMenuIcon
        .Caption = Sheets("FontAwesome").Cells(WrdArray(0), 1)
        .top = (30 * i) + 9
        .left = 0
        .Width = 30
        .Height = 20
        .ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        .BackStyle = fmBackStyleTransparent
        .Font.Name = "FontAwesome"
        .Font.Size = 14
        .TextAlign = fmTextAlignCenter
        .MousePointer = fmMousePointerCustom
        .MouseIcon = LoadPicture(Application.ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Creative\Other\Hand.cur")
        .Tag = "-021"
    End With

    With lblMenuText
        .Caption = WrdArray(1)
        .top = (30 * i) + 8
        .left = 30
        .Width = 90
        .Height = 20
        .ForeColor = RGB(0, 0, 0)
        .BackStyle = fmBackStyleTransparent
        .Font.Size = 12
        .MousePointer = fmMousePointerCustom
        .MouseIcon = LoadPicture(Application.ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Creative\Other\Hand.cur")
        .Tag = "-021"
    End With

Loop

Close #FileNum

End Sub
```

Ok, so a brief overview of whats happeing here...

I open a data file `MenuItems.csv` for input. I assign each line within this file to `i`. I then `Set` three individual `MSForms.Label`(s):

1. `lblMenuBackground`
2. `lblMenuIcon`
3. `lblMenuText`

...and build them asynchronously.

You will notice that after building the first label (`lblMenuBackground`), I assign a custom class event `lbl(i).lblEvent1 = lblMenuBackground`.

*(It is important that I use `ReDim Preserve` correctly here so that each sequential menu item gains this custom class, and not just the last one.)*

Code within `cMenuItem` class module

```
Public WithEvents lblEvent1 As MSForms.Label

Private Sub lblEvent1_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)

Dim ctl As Control
    For Each ctl In frmTest.frmMenuBackground.Controls
        If TypeName(ctl) = "Label" Then
            If Not ctl.BackColor = RGB(GetB(mdTheme.frmThemeID6), GetG(mdTheme.frmThemeID6), GetR(mdTheme.frmThemeID6)) Then ctl.BackColor = RGB(GetB(mdTheme.frmThemeID6), GetG(mdTheme.frmThemeID6), GetR(mdTheme.frmThemeID6))
        End If
    Next ctl

Me.lblEvent1.BackColor = RGB(GetB(mdTheme.frmThemeID2), GetG(mdTheme.frmThemeID2), GetR(mdTheme.frmThemeID2))

End Sub
```

*(Please ignore the `.BackColor` property complexity here as it could get <s>even more</s> confusing, and is un-related to this question.)*

After `UserForm_Activate`, here is the updated form:

[image]

*(You may notice the use of FontAwesome icons here.)*

Because I have added a custom `MouseOver` class event to each `lblMenuBackground` label, mousing over causes the `.BackColor` to change:

[image]

## Here is my issue...

This mouse over effect is only triggered when the cursor passes over one of the three labels that make up each menu item.

`lblMenuBackground`

### Why?

I only know how to affect the called control's properties.

Or rather...

I don't know how to affect un-called control properties from within the called control's event.

Here is the structure of each menu item:

[image]

## Here is my question...

[image]

How can I affect the `.BackColor` of the same control from the `MouseOver` events of all three individual controls which make up each menu item?

1. Moves cursor over icon = Background colour changes
2. Moves cursor over text = Background colour changes
3. Moves cursor over background = Background colour changes

The class event needs to be assigned at build time...

> ```
> ReDim Preserve lbl(1 To i)
> Set lbl(i).lblEvent1 = lblMenuBackground
> ```

...for each menu item.

`End`<s>Sub</s>`Question`

## __________

This logic will fundamentally lay the foundations for my interface.

For those of you who made it this far - thank you for reading!

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,

Mr. J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on hooking into the events for `lblMenuBackground`

> lbl(i).lblEvent1 = lblMenuBackground

### Modify BuildMenuItems

Change

> Set lbl(i).lblEvent1 = lblMenuBackground

to

> Set lbl(i) = New cMenuItem
>
> lbl(i).setControls lblMenuBackground, lblMenuIcon, lblMenuText

### Modify CMenuItem Class

```
Public WithEvents m_lblMenuBackground As MSForms.Label
Public WithEvents m_lblMenuIcon As MSForms.Label
Public WithEvents m_lblMenuText As MSForms.Label

Public Sub setControls(lblMenuBackground As MSForms.Label, lblMenuIcon As MSForms.Label, lblMenuText As MSForms.Label)
    Set m_lblMenuBackground = lblMenuBackground
    Set m_lblMenuIcon = lblMenuIcon
    Set m_lblMenuText = lblMenuText
End Sub
    
Private Sub m_lblMenuBackground_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    Update
End Sub

Private Sub m_lblMenuIcon_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    Update
End Sub

Private Sub m_lblMenuText_MouseMove(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
    Update
End Sub

Private Sub Update()
    Dim ctl As Control
    For Each ctl In frmTest.frmMenuBackground.Controls
        If TypeName(ctl) = "Label" Then
            If Not ctl.BackColor = RGB(GetB(mdTheme.frmThemeID6), GetG(mdTheme.frmThemeID6), GetR(mdTheme.frmThemeID6)) Then ctl.BackColor = RGB(GetB(mdTheme.frmThemeID6), GetG(mdTheme.frmThemeID6), GetR(mdTheme.frmThemeID6))
        End If
    Next ctl

    Me.m_lblMenuBackground.BackColor = RGB(GetB(mdTheme.frmThemeID2), GetG(mdTheme.frmThemeID2), GetR(mdTheme.frmThemeID2))
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for your comment, I like where you're going with this! I'm getting a compile error though, see my above edit...

Comment: @Mr.J I updated my answer.  I made a small change to the class also.

Comment: absolute perfection! Exactly what I was looking for, thank you kind sir :)

Comment: thanks, I'm slowly building a [bracket](https://themeforest.net/item/bracket-responsive-bootstrap-3-admin-template/6894362) themed interface for statistical analysis and reporting :)

Comment: @Mr.J Very nice.  I think that I would use another custom class `cMenuItems` hold a collection of `cMenuItem`.  The idea is that the new `cMenuItems` class would track the active `cMenuItem` group.   This way only the previous active group and the newly active group would be reformatted and if active group mouseover event re-fires then you would not have to reformat anything.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand fully. Menu items are built upon form activation once only. Each menu item has its class event assigned at build time. Can you explain your concerns around 'reformatting' and the difference between the 'previously active' and 'newly active' groups?

Comment: @Mr.J The `MouseMove` event will fire several times as the cursor moves across a control.  But if you don't get any lag or flickering then don't worry about it.

Comment: Right I'm with you now. There's no lag or flickering whatsoever. Thanks again.